# Packages hyperref together with subfig break when \renewcommand{\thefigure}{...} is used

Tags: floats, hyperref, errors, subfloats

The following code compiles and acts as you would expect:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{$\dag$}
\subfloat[Sub-dagger]
{
\label{subfloat:first}
Hello there my good sport
}%
\qquad
\subfloat[Sub-dagger the other]
{
Hello again nice to see you
}
\caption{Daggered figure}
\label{fig:dag}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{fig:dag} shows two things... one of them is sub-figure \ref{subfloat:first}.

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

However, when `%\usepackage{hyperref}` is uncommented, the following error is given:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\curr@fontshape ->\f@encoding 
                              /\f@family /\f@series /\f@shape 
l.11 \subfloat
              [Sub-dagger]
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

No error occurs if no subfloats are in the figure, either.  The error occurs even if `\listoffigures` is commented out.

A remark: if `$\dag$` is replaced by `$a$`, or by `ABC`, the code compiles fine.  It seems like there is some issue with the amount of memory `$\dag$` takes, which is strange to me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as I did in my edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of using `subfig` you could use the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{$\dag$}
\subcaptionbox{First subfigure\label{subfloat:first}}{Hello there my good sport}\qquad
\subcaptionbox{Second subfigure\label{subfloat:second}}{Hello again nice to see you}
\caption{Daggered figure}
\label{fig:dag}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{fig:dag} shows two things... one of them is sub-figure \ref{subfloat:first}.

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]

On a side note, except for some exceptions, `hyperref` should be the last package to load.

If switching to `subcaption` is not an option, then you can use the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\specialcaption[1]{%
  \@namedef{the\@captype}{#1}%
  \addtocounter{\@captype}{-1}\caption}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\makeatletter
\def\p@subfigure{$\dag$} 
\makeatother
\subfloat[Sub-dagger]
{%
\label{subfloat:first}
Hello there my good sport
}%
\qquad
\subfloat[Sub-dagger the other]
{%
Hello again nice to see you
}
\specialcaption{$\dag$}{Daggered figure}
\label{fig:dag}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{fig:dag} shows two things... one of them is sub-figure \ref{subfloat:first}.

\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice the spurious blank spaces that I removed by using the `%` character.

Comment: My whole thesis is already formatted with subfig, and it is a daunting thought to go through and change all of it... do you know why this problem is happening?

Comment: @Andrey I see. Please see my updated answer for a work-around using `subfig`.

Comment: @Andrey I had initially forgotten some code; now I've corrected the example.