# Wrong numbering in the List of Figures with subfigure package

Tags: numbering, subfloats

I get a wrong numbering of subfigures in the List of Figures with the following MWE.

If I remove the `FIGTOPCAP` option or if I put the `\caption` on the top, the problem is solved, but I'd like keep them. Any idea?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[tight,FIGTOPCAP]{subfigure}
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
    \frame{
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            PIC 1
        \end{minipage}
    }
    \caption[Short Caption]{Long Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \subfigure[Sub-caption A]{\label{LabelA}%
        \frame{
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
                PIC 2A
            \end{minipage}
        }%
    }
    \hfill
    \subfigure[Sub-caption B]{\label{labelB}%
        \frame{
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
                PIC 2B
            \end{minipage}
        }%
    }%
    \caption[General Short Caption]{General Long Caption\label{GenLabel}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you get the desired output with `\usepackage[tight]{subfigure} \subfiguretopcaptrue` in the preamble?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel please either post an answer, or vote to close TL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `subfigure` package has long be declared obsolete. You get correct output with the successor package `subfig` (notice that you must use `\subfloat` instead of `\subfigure` and `\subtable`); the `\captionsetup` is drawn from the documentation to emulate the old options.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{subfig}
\captionsetup[subfloat]{position=top,
  farskip=10pt,topadjust=0pt,captionskip=10pt,
  nearskip=10pt,margin=10pt}

\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
\framebox[0.4\textwidth]{PIC 1}
\caption[Short Caption]{Long Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\subfloat[Sub-caption A]{\label{LabelA}%
  \framebox[0.4\textwidth]{PIC 2A}%
}%
\hfill
\subfloat[Sub-caption B]{\label{labelB}%
  \framebox[0.4\textwidth]{PIC 2A}%
}

\caption[General Short Caption]{General Long Caption\label{GenLabel}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here is the "List of figures"

[image]

and here's the part with the subfloats

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know I was working with an obsolete package. Definitely I am goning to use this code.

Comment: There is one small mistake I can't resolve. When you add 'hyperref' package and '\chapter{Chap. 1}' after '\listoffigures' entry, you get a bad numbering in LOF, actually there are two warning about that. Do you know how resolve it? I appreciate any idea...

Comment: @Gitano I'm afraid that `subfig` is no longer compatible with `hyperref` and switching to `subcaption` is the best thing you can do. See [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59514/packages-hyperref-together-with-subfig-break-when-renewcommand-thefigure)

Answer (score 3):

The options `FIGTOPCAP` (and `FIGBOTCAP`) controls the settings for the normal caption as well as the subfigure’s caption. In your example, the subfigure’s caption were allocated to the first figure because they appeared after the first and before the second `\caption`.

The [`subfigure`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) package offers three so called “flags” (→ [`subfigure` manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subfigure), 4.5 “Aligning Captions Above the Figure”, pp. 23f.):

- `\subfiguretopcaptrue`
- `\subfiguretopcapfalse`
- `\figuretopcaptrue`

Admittedly, I can’t fully follow the explanations and examples from the manual; the solution is to drop the `FIGTOPCAP` option and use `\subfiguretopcaptrue` (preferably in the preamble), as it does exactly what it says on the tin.

### Code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[tight]{subfigure}
\subfiguretopcaptrue
\setcounter{lofdepth}{2}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}
    \frame{
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
            PIC 1
        \end{minipage}
    }
    \caption[Short Caption]{Long Caption}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
    \subfigure[Sub-caption A]{\label{LabelA}%
        \frame{
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
                PIC 2A
            \end{minipage}
        }%
    }
    \hfill
    \subfigure[Sub-caption B]{\label{labelB}%
        \frame{
            \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
                PIC 2B
            \end{minipage}
        }%
    }%
    \caption[General Short Caption]{General Long Caption\label{GenLabel}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]